# Why does an error appear when connecting to the server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have such a problem that when I did an http server on sockets (website), everything was fine, but then when I try to connect through the browser, an error pops up.
here is the code:

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5000)) 
s.listen(9000) 
conn, addr = s.accept() 


data = conn.recv(1024) 
print(f'Received: \n {data.decode()}')
time.sleep(10)
conn.sendall('HTTP/1.1 201 Created \n'.encode('UTF-8'))
time.sleep(2)
conn.sendall('Server : pythonsite/0.0.1 \n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('Date: \n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('Content-Type: application/octet-stream \n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('Content-Length: 7 \n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('Last-Modified: \n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('Connection: keep-alive \n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('Accept-Ranges: bytes \n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('\n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('\n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('<html>\n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('<head>\n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('<title>pythonserv!</title>\n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('</head>\n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('<body>\n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('<p>this is python web!!!</p>\n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('</body>\n'.encode('UTF-8'))
conn.sendall('</html>\n'.encode('UTF-8'))
time.sleep(3)
data = conn.recv(1024)
time.sleep(8)
print(f'Received: \n {data.decode()}')
    
conn.close()
```

error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Михаил Балошко/Downloads/dz/test_ekrana.py", line 16, in 
conn.sendall('Server : pythonsite/0.0.1 \n'.encode('UTF-8'))
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение

I tried deleting part of the code and setting time.sleep() but it doesn't help

Comment: Please update the question to include the error.

Comment: What error pops up?

Comment: error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Михаил Балошко/Downloads/dz/test_ekrana.py", line 16, in <module>
    conn.sendall('Server : pythonsite/0.0.1 \n'.encode('UTF-8'))
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение

Comment: I think Error 10053 is connection aborted.  The other side closed the conneciton on you.  Possibly because you took too long (waiting 10 seconds is a very long time on a socket connection).  Try more like 0.1s if you must have a sleep.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Even if it is not that hard, HTTP protocol may be tedious to correctly implement. What is the reason for not using an already existing module for that?

Answer (score 0):

A browser will abort the connection when the server does not send a correct HTTP message.

HTTP uses carriage return/line feed for line termination. Replace `\n` by `\r\n`.

Your Content-Type header is wrong. It should be "text/html".

Your Content-Length header is wrong. It should match the actual length of the payload (the HTML page).

You should use only one empty line between the headers and the payload.